# How : neither a relative pronoun nor a relative adverb

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, subordinators

> Relative pronoun : who, whom, whose, which, that
>
> Relative adverb : when, where, why

Is "how" *neither a relative pronoun nor a relative adverb*? Is 'how' only a *subordinating conjunction* in a noun clause?

Comment: Sandip, what research did you do? Where did your dictionaries and search engines give up?

Comment: Appending 'how' after a noun sounds wrong in any context. So, I think 'how' isn't a relative element. It's a 'subordinator' in a subordinate content clause.

Comment: Thanks and still Sandip, what research did you do? Where did your dictionaries and search engines give up? Who says "appending 'how' after a noun sounds wrong"?

Comment: It's in every grammar book that 'when', 'where' and 'why' are relative adverbs. Michael Swan says that "The way how" is wrong. 'How' means 'the way'. 'How' is used in content clauses (in noun clauses, in traditional grammar).

Comment: Sandip, I don't want to be pedantic but it can be in every grammar book and here, it's recognised as being in only those grammar books you list, and only on the pages and in the contexts you cite.

Otherwise what are you relying on but "everyone knows"?